# Run Script on Starting rqt_gui Shell Plugin

Tags: ros, shell, plugin, startup, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been looking to automate a setup for rqt_gui, and I was wondering if there was any way to run a script on startup of an rqt_gui Shell plugin object. I know the shell currently acts normally and sources the .bashrc when started, but I was hoping that I could make a small script that would only be run in this shell (not in any normal shell I might use). I'm not too sure this is actually possible, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask, if only to find out it can't be done easily.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53724/run-script-on-starting-rqt_gui-shell-plugin/) by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is currently not supported, but could be implemented.
First as background info, rqt_shell offers three different backends for the actual command shell:

1. one doing a simple single command shell call for each command given
2. one based on the Spyder project's shell
3. one using an actual XTerm instance and just embedding its window into rqt_gui

For 1) the script would have to be executed every time before the command, since the shell used only lives for the execution time of that single command.

For 2) the script has to be run once after the shell is set up.

For 3) the script would have to be passed as command line parameter when starting the XTerm instance.

Please feel free to supply patches implementing any or preferably all of these.

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3